# Why people don't notice separate websites for special topics on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta

A little example stats before I start:

Stack Overflow has 19,422 questions on [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress), and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com has fewer total questions.

So, my point is if the community has created a separate website for Q&A related to wordpress, why allow the [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag here?

What is Stack Overflow? A general bucket of every type of question?

Comment: Same as the people who don't know about meta....

Comment: I posted it here because I think it will get noticed. Meta has less attention either!

Comment: @dar - what makes you think that meta gets *less* attention? (says lix with his [meta fanatic badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/53/fanatic))

Comment: @DarshanThanki: You are conflating number of questions with popularity. SO has been around much longer, it had more time to build a community.

Comment: Yes, I am agree with you. and H2CO3's answer is somehow relevant to the question.

Comment: *"I posted it here [main SO] because I think it will get noticed."* -- that's simply bad.

Comment: I was a baby when I posted it.. Now I am getting older and smarter! :D

Comment: Wordpress actively migrates PHP/etc only questions that don't have to do with any Wordpress specific functionality. I suspect some questions like that might still end up tagged "wordpress" even though it's not necessarily relevant to the question.

Answer (score 10):

This mostly happens when there's an overlap between Stack Overflow and the more focused site.  There are a lot of WordPress questions that involve programming, so they're not technically off-topic on Stack Overflow, so we don't close/migrate them.

Contrast that with the question on the [TeX/LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) site, which we used to accept as on-topic on SO.  Now they have ten times as many questions on that site as we have on the [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) tag.  They also average over 50 new questions per day, whereas we only get a trickle of new LaTeX question on SO.

Comment: I love the idea of opening new dedicated website for a topic. and I just did not want to compare it with the number of questions, but on relevance.

Answer (score 5):

> I posted it here because I think it will get noticed.

Consider the possibility that the people posting questions on wordpress in the wrong place are at least as smart as you.

Now look again at your reasons for posting your comment in the wrong place. Think about how they probably want their postings to get noticed and thereby answered. See the answer yet?

Comment: With one major difference: asking non-programming questions about SO is off topic on SO. Period. Asking about PHP in WordPress might very well be on topic though.

Answer (score 2):

Because some people are...

- ...lazy. They don't make the effort to fire up Google and search for a relevant site for their questions. They heard about Stack Overflow once, and without reading the FAQ, they think that it's for every question they might have, starting from the sexual problems of their ex-wife through the politcal and economical state of the country, etc.
- ...not smart enough to realize some topics are irrelevant for some sites. I'm an active pariticipant on Stack Overflow and I repeatedly encounter people claiming themselves to be "programmers" with the intelligence, logic and language skills of a 3-year old.
- etc. Miscellaneous reasons also might arise, however as far as I know (and have experienced), the two above are the main reasons.

Comment: Vote up for the answer! Exactly what I think.

Comment: I think quite a number of people fit into your 2nd reason might be due to their language skill. The low language skill will affect the person's ability to convey his/her thought and the ability to understand what is written.

Comment: @nhahtdh agreed.

Comment: You may well be correct; there are certainly people asking questions on SO who don't have the first clue about what they're talking about. But, society and more specifically this community, can and will be judged by how the least competent / knowledgeable / etc are treated. I'm not suggesting that everyone should kowtow to someone who's plainly incompetent and I don't even mind a bit of subtle snark but this answer _seems_ contemptuous. There's reason not to be polite. You don't even need to engage; you can vote to close or flag for moving to wordpress.se if question is worthy.

Comment: @Ben and I'm doing it also regularily. The problem is that I remember being a n00b and **not** having done this. You can also see my questions on SO - they're not of the same quality as the question asking why the statements in a function weren't executed after a `return;` (yes, that happened). This and similar stuff should be looked up in a tutorial and/or googled, but they're definitely not to be asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: You don't need to convince me of that; I've answered one where they were expecting code to be executed after a return :-).

Answer (score 1):

Ignorance. People don't always know about other sites - Stack Overflow is the big rock star site.

People post on sites without reading the FAQ, etc. In fact, j'accuse you of the same, but maybe not quite.

I think it's down to the fact that this is an evolving community; things like this become issues, and solutions will be prepared to solve them.

So, basically, it will change if enough people care.

Comment: I also posted this question on SO, but for getting people note it. I joined meta after is my question is migrated to meta.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of questions are related to [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress), but they are much more general and involve only little WordPress-specific knowledge.

I wouldn't be interested in visiting a WordPress-only Stack Exchange site, but I was able to [answer the question *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217821/test-if-a-wordpress-page-exists-using-javascript-before-redirecting-to-it/12217837#12217837*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217821/test-if-a-wordpress-page-exists-using-javascript-before-redirecting-to-it/12217837#12217837).

I'd say that the greatest part of my answer is general and only a small, easy, point (debated in comments) is specific to WordPress.

So this question was better asked on Stack Overflow than on a specific Stack Exchange site in my opinion. And I suspect that this is often the case; experienced developers are rarely knowing only one field.

Answer (score 1):

Poor Inter-stack connection: If a question has the tags "Math" and "History" why should the same question, comments, and answers not appear on both the Math and the History sites?

Asking the same question on two different sites results in one of the answers being overlooked-especially if the viewer comes from a search engine. Answers and comments by a historian are likely to be appreciated by a mathematician.

I have been thinking about this for a while and posted [more details in a question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145738/should-stack-exchange-adopt-a-portolan-structure).