# "Inter-Stack" Feature for Questions Deserving of Multiple Stacks.

Tags: feature-request

Perhaps an "inter-stack" feature could be added to deal with question like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/is-there-a-term-for-the-old-maps-that-had-lines-connecting-pin-wheels) that are applicable on [another stack](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/is-there-a-term-for-the-old-maps-that-had-lines-connecting-pin-wheels/2833#2833) as well. Such a feature would allow a single question and answers to appear on multiple sites. Reputation and badges could be awarded to the stack from-which the viewer came - or in the case of search-engine traffic make the user choose which stack to join before upvoting.

Comment: I think this makes the most sense on the Science sites (eg Chem + physics or Bio + Cognitive Sciences) but a similar proposal was made...which I can't currently find

Comment: @BenBrocka It was [Manish's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration) proposal for "soft migration".

Comment: @jonsca that's the one. Could have swore it was Mad Scientist's. No wonder I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a question that is potentially on-topic for multiple sites, the best thing to do is play to the strengths of each site by asking a tailored question that focuses on the aspect that is most topical for each site. You will get much higher quality answers to a specific question that is more focused on the aspect of the question related to the site scope.

Each community has different approaches to questions and the extra time invested in learning these and adapting questions to them is well worth the effort.

Catering a feature to people who want to ask broad questions and are too lazy to spend the extra time to narrow down their scope or cater them do a different community is not something that I think would generally enhance the quality of content on the SE network.